# generate godoc documentation for an entire project?

Tags: go, godoc

I've been wrestling with godoc and found that "go doc" is more for providing  usage help from the command line for instance:

```
go doc -cmd -u
```

lists the package comment and any functions (or other entities)

```
go doc *function*
```

then shows the documentation for an individual function (or other entity)

It seems there is a related tool called *godoc*. 
godoc also seems to generate html on a per package and function basis.
E.g.

```
godoc -html hello
```

Generates html containing the package comment only to stdout

*godoc* is a really confusing name given we have *go doc* as well!

**How can I create static documentation for the whole project?**

This is similar to [Godoc, create html for entire package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331224/godoc-create-html-for-entire-package) which may have been misinterpreted as asking about documentation for packages rather than projects.
I want a build step I can use in a project that may in principle contain many packages and apps.

Comment: The official Go installer installs `godoc` by default.  Command line use of `godoc` to print documentation will be phased out in the next release of Go.  At the same time, the `go doc` command will gain the ability to print the doc for an entire package.

Comment: First: Always install the official Go releases and not some old debian packages. `go doc` is a command line tool and integrates well into editors or IDEs while `godoc -http :6060` lets you browse the whole documentation of all your Go packages.

Comment: The Debian package does not (or at least not obviously) include godoc. I see https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25595 will add support for this to "go doc --all" for 1.12. I'm not sure what to do for godoc for now though

Comment: if you can consider to use an alternative, try `gvm`

Comment: If a package depends on a particular minimum Go version, older Go installations cannot produce documentation for that package. Go needs accurate and complete type information to do that, and older versions simply don't know about new additions to the standard library; let alone new language features (i.e syntax).

Comment: All very well but is there a canonical way to generate documentation for offline use even using godoc?

Comment: The comments above are now redundant. They refer to an earlier version of the question where I was using go 1.7.4 supplied by Debian 9 which does not provide the 'godoc' and has been considered obsolete by the go community for some time. If you are passing by and have sufficient rep - consider deleting some of them.

Answer (score 17):

> is there a canonical way to generate documentation for offline use even using godoc?

[Go 1.12 (February 2019)](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.12#godoc) is clearer on that:

> ### `godoc` and `go doc`
>
> **In Go 1.12, `godoc` no longer has a command-line interface and is only a web server.**
>   Users should use `go doc` for command-line help output instead.
>
> [`go doc` now supports the `-all` flag](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/141977/), which will cause it to print all exported APIs and their documentation, as the `godoc` command line used to do.
>
> `cmd/doc`: add `-all` flag to print all documentation for package
>
> Unlike the one for the old `godoc`, you need the `-u` flag to see unexported symbols.
>   This seems like the right behavior: it's consistent.

Comment: -all does a _package_ not the entire _project_

Comment: @BruceAdams True (as stated in this answer). I'll have to test a `go doc -all ./...` triggers the doc for *all* packages (https://stackoverflow.com/q/28031603/6309)

Comment: Today that produces "too many periods in symbol specification"

Comment: @VivaLaPanda Which command produces that error message? On which OS? With which version of Go? I just tested `go doc -all` and it seems to be working just fine.

Comment: @VonC `go doc -all ./...` produces the `too many periods` error mentioned by @VivaLaPanda. I'm on MacOS 13.1, running Go 1.19.3 (ARM64)

Comment: @Tijmen OK, what is the proper syntax for `go doc` to operate on current and all sub-packages?

Comment: @VonC I don't know; I came here trying to learn that, but ended up going with the curl approach

Comment: @Tijmen OK. What is the `curl` approach in this case?

Comment: @VonC, ah, my mistake, I meant to say the `wget` approach. As outlined in braj's answer below, and Roberto's comment on that answer.

Answer (score 5):

I was struggling to do this and finally, the thing that worked for me is

1. make sure you have "wget" installed(I am using mac, so had to install it using x-code)
2. log in as root user and modify the file called "robots.txt" to remove the line "Disallow : /" as this prevents wget to download the site recursively. The "robots.txt" file should be in $GOROOT path.
3. open a cmd and start the godocs server using the below command

   ```
   godoc -http=:6060
   ```

   I have my local path configured to this port.
4. Open another cmd and run the below command.

   ```
   wget -r -np -N -E -p -k http://localhost:6060/pkg/myproject
   ```

   you can mention the path of the project to have the html docs downloaded for entire project.

Comment: You can ask wget to ignore robots with `-e robots=off`

Comment: @braj I know I'm a little late to the party, but have you heard of `homebrew`? It's basically `dpkg` or `apt` for macOS. Almost every part of my macOS devops toolchain was installed using the `brew` command. Check it out: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-homebrew-on-macos

Comment: How is homebrew relevant here? 
Having to run a web-server and download the documentation is backwards. Rather you should be able to generate static documentation and serve it as you will. Contrast with doxygen.  
Switching to root is an even bigger no no.
The convenience of a web-server is great but it should be opt-in.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Golds](https://github.com/go101/golds), which is an alternate Go docs generation tool (and a local docs server / code reader).

Under your project directory, you can run any of the following commands to generate HTML docs for your Go project:

- golds -gen -nouses -plainsrc -wdpkgs-listing=promoted ./...
- golds -gen -nouses -wdpkgs-listing=promoted ./...
- golds -gen -wdpkgs-listing=promoted ./...

The first command generates the most compact docs and the last one generates the full docs, which size is 6 times of the compact docs.

BTW, I'm the author of **Golds**. Hope you this tool would satisfy your need.

Comment: Thanks! Awesome tool :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be also achieved using simple **wget** command for that. Example: [snippet](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1977141)

I have a similar issue with that. I'm using GitLab for my projects and I have decide to create and share with some handy GitLab CI YAML templates for Go projects that will automatically generate a static HTML Go documentation without any external packages: https://gitlab.com/tymonx/gitlab-ci

Example: [Go Logger documentation](https://tymonx.gitlab.io/go-logger/doc/pkg/gitlab.com/tymonx/go-logger/logger/)

Two nice features:

- Embedded Go source code files
- Search box is referencing to GitLab