# How to generate html docs in go/golang?

Tags: go, doc

Trying to generate docs for my go package but not sure `how to generate html docs`

Tried with `go doc` but it just spits out the text version but I want html version.

looking at `go help doc` there is something that says about html `go doc template.new` but not sure how to use it.

Also tried with godoc, but unable to make it work.

installed it with

```
go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc
```

and it is present in the directory `golang.org/x/tools/cmd`

but when I try to run it using `go tool godoc` it throws an error saying:

`go:no such tool godoc`

and nothing in go `bin` folder that i can use.

Can anyone please tell, how can i make it work?

Comment: FYI the command is `godoc` not `go tool godoc`.

Comment: yes that's what i been finding everywhere, but whenever i run i always get `godoc: command not found` so i thought i should run `go tool godoc` as it is also in tools cmd directory.

Comment: @mkopriva Also in godoc README they says `This directory contains most of the code for running a godoc server. The
executable lives at golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc.` but there is no executable there and not in go `bin` directory?

Comment: Probably because you haven't installed the tool. Use `go install`. In older versions the `go get` command used to also install tools but it doesn't anymore.

Comment: See https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Add_dependencies_to_current_module_and_install_them *"In earlier versions of Go, 'go get' was used to build and install packages. Now, 'go get' is dedicated to adjusting dependencies in go.mod. 'go install' may be used to build and install commands instead."* and https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_and_install_packages_and_dependencies

Comment: @mkopriva thanks! it generated the binary in go `bin` directory after running `go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just another thing, is `go doc` can produce html doc like `godoc` does as that is also the part of my question. If you can answer that, i'll really appreciate!

Comment: `go doc` cannot generate html. If it could it would say so in `go help doc`.

Comment: @mkopriva but in here: `https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go/internal/doc` there is `go doc template.new
  Show documentation for html/template's New function.
  (html/template is lexically before text/template)` Can we use it somehow to generate html docs?

Comment: No, that's just an example of how you can show the documentation of a function in a package. `New` is the function and `html/template` is the pacakge. To show its documentation you can do `go doc html/template.new`. That's all that it says. It doesn't say anything about generating HTML output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I generate HTML documents using \`godoc\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530120/how-can-i-generate-html-documents-using-godoc)